# Check content of an element inside a ListView with Espresso

Tags: android, listview, android-espresso

How can I check that the information of an item inside a ListView is correctly displayed.

[image]

I need to check that **TODO Title Sample** which is an TextView and **TODO Location Sample** which is also a TextView are correctly displayed with this texts using Espresso. I have the following code, but it is not working:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.to_do_list_view)).atPosition(0).
               check(matches(withChild(withId(R.id.item_title)).matches(withText("TODO Title Sample"))));
```

Any idea how I can solve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to figure it out, and it is quite simple:

```
onData(anything()).inAdapterView(withId(R.id.to_do_list_view)).atPosition(0).
               onChildView(withId(R.id.item_title)).
               check(matches(withText("TODO Title Sample")));
```